# Error: Cannot find symbol when passing and returning variables

Tags: java, parameter-passing, cannot-find-symbol

Rookie mistake? 
Hello, I'm a first-year computer science student and I keep getting cannot find symbol errors. I declared the variable in the main method, passed it to another method, modified it, and then returned it. For some reason, the compiler cannot find the symbols result, input, and points. I'm sure it's the same reason for all of them. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Fishing
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      do
      {
         String input;     //Holds user input
         int points;      // Holds player's points
         int score = 0;   // Sets player's score to 0
         final int DIE_SIDES = 6;    // # of sides for the die

         //Create an instance of the Die class
         Die die = new Die(DIE_SIDES);

         //Roll the die once and store value in result
         die.roll();
         int result = die.getValue();

         getScore(points, result);
         String input = getInput();

         //Keeps running total of player's score
         score = score + points;

      } while (input == "yes");
      System.out.print(0);
   }

   /**
     The getScore method will calculate the player's score
     depending on what the player rolled. It will also show
     a message and return the score.
     @return A reference to an integer object containing
             the player's score for one roll.
   */

   public static int getScore(int points, int result)
   {
      if (result == 1)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Waaaaahhhhh, you have caught " +
                                   "a shark. Sharks are dangerous. You " +
                                        "have been awarded zero points.");
         points = 0;
         return points;
     }
     else if (result == 2)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught a jellyfish. " +
                              "This beautiful creature has awarded you " +
                                                           "50 points!!");
         points = 50;
         return points;
     }
     else if (result == 3)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught an old boot. " +
                            "Maybe you can sell this old boot after it " +
                             "dries out. You have been awarded 1 point.");
         points = 1;
         return points;
     }
     else if (result == 4)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught an Alaskan salmon. " +
                            "This delicious and popular fish has awarded you " +
                                                                "75 points!!!");
         points = 75;
         return points;
     }  
     else if (result == 5)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught a small fish. You " +
                                               "have been awarded 20 points!");                                                                                
         points = 20;
         return points;
     }
     else
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have caught a treasure chest!! " +
                              "It is filled with shining pieces of gold, and " +
                                        "you have been awarded 100 points!!!!");
         points = 100;
         return points;
     }
  }

   /**
      The getInput method will receive the user's input
      and return it to the main method.
      @return A reference to a String input value containing
              the user's response.
   */  

    public static String getInput()
    {
        //Prompt user to enter response
        response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to play another " +
                                   "round of fishing? Enter yes or no.");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify what line of code you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

We need to make the following changes:

- `Result` is declared in `main()` method and hence, it is local to `main()` only. `getScore` has no knowledge of it. If we want to access `result`, `input` and `points` in `getScore()` method then we need to pass all of them to `getScore()`.
- `getInput()` returns an input. So, we don't need to pass any argument to it. We can change `getInput(String response)` to `getInput()` and modify `main()` so that value returned by `getInput()` is assigned to `input` variable (`input = getInput();`)
- [Here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_method_parameters.html) are some basics of parameter passing in java. I would recommend going through it.

Comment: I made the modifications, but in line 24 I am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question with changes? Also, what do we have on line 24?

Comment: I changed the code and line 24 is } while (input == "yes");. The only error I'm getting is this line because of the input variable.

Comment: where is line 24 anyway

Comment: We need to declare `input` variable outside the `do-while` loop.